# Two irrational numbers are congruent iff the tails of their infinite continued fractions eventually coincide

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

We say that a real number $\alpha$ is $congruent$ to real number $\beta$ if there exist integers a, b, c and d with ad-bc=+1 or -1 and such that $$\alpha=\frac{a\beta +b}{c\beta+d}$$ I need to prove that two irrational numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are congruent if and only if the tails of their infinite continued franctions expansions eventually agree, this means: 
$$\alpha=[\alpha_0;\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n,e_1,e_2,...]$$ and $$\beta=[\beta_0;\beta_1,\beta_2,...,\beta_j,e_1,e_2,...]$$

So, I started doing the second direction (If their continued fractions eventually coincide, then they are congruent), but I got to here and I dont know what else to do: 
$$\alpha=(\alpha_0+\alpha_1+...+\alpha_n)+\beta+(\beta_0+\beta_1+...+\beta_j)$$ (I know all of the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_k$ are integer). I need help in both directions, and I dont know where to start the other one.

Comment: Does the term "complete quotient" sound familiar? Do you know how to express $x$ in terms of convergents and complete quotients of $x$?

Comment: This is conceptually similar to a [Mobius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobius_transformation).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's been almost three years since your question, it's probably no longer of interest to you but the answer might be useful for someone else who comes across this page.

Anyways, here's the answer: this is a theorem in Hardy and Wright's classic book, "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers", page 141 - 143 in the fifth edition, section 10.11. It's a very nice proof, and most good math libraries will have this book.